# Can I hide a domain while using a proxy?

Tags: php, https, proxy, dns

I'm wondering if I can **completely** encrypt a request sent through a 3rd party proxy server.

HTTPS request contents should be invisible to the proxy, however the domain where the request goes to is visible.

Is there any solution to hide the domain name, so that the proxy cannot see that data is being sent to `https://example.com`?

I've read some stuff about DNScrypt but it sounds like that is not applicable when you are routing requests through a proxy.

Some side notes:

- I am using a proxy with cURL through PHP.
- Its running on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: "so that the proxy cannot see that data is being sent to https://example.com" ...well, a big part of the proxy's job to forward the request on to the destination server, so if you attempt to hide the destination, how would you expect it to route the request correctly? Why do you want to do this anyway? Are you attempting to access a site which is forbidden by the proxy? There are potentially other ways to achieve that (e.g. VPN) if it's allowed...but then the fact you used a VPN will be visible to the proxy instead.

Comment: Well i was hoping there would be some sort of encryption technology. Yes my proxy is prohibiting requests for a certain list of domains. Im fine with setting up a VPN for this but I need some sort of overview of how this would work then.

Comment: With a VPN the proxy would see a connection to the VPN server only. The VPN server then (effectively) acts as another proxy and forwards your request on to the final destination. But if your network is blocking certain sites by policy then there's a good chance they're not fans of VPN services either, since it allows people to work around their blocking policy and thus makes it ineffective. So you may find that most of the well-known VPN services are also blocked.

Comment: " i was hoping there would be some sort of encryption technology" ...again it's unclear what you would expect this to achieve or how it would work? let's use an analogy - in this example, the proxy server is replaced by a good old-fashioned postman at the local sorting office. Imagine you're posting a letter and you didn't want the postman to know who it was intended for, because you're not allowed to send letters to that person. So you write the address in a secret code. That's great...the postman can't see who you're writing to. But...they also don't know where else to deliver the letter.

Comment: If you encrypt the information about the destination, and thus hide the destination from the person delivering the message, then they cannot deliver it. That is a fundamental logical impossibility. So I just can't understand what you think encryption is going to do for you? Can you explain? (P.S. In this analogy, using a VPN is like putting your letter with a forbidden address inside another envelope and writing a valid address on it, and putting a note inside asking the recipient to forward the inner envelope to the destination via a different postal company).

Comment: (The slight difference with a real VPN is that (because of the use of HTTPS) the postman cannot open the envelope and therefore see that you are actually trying to access a different address, they can only see the outer, permitted address of the VPN server. This is the same with any HTTPs request (unless of course your proxy server terminates your HTTPs request there and replaces it with another outbound HTTPs connection, which some do - effectively a Man-in-the-middle attack, but an officially sanctioned one.)

Comment: i think the VPN connection suits my purpose then, so that the proxy only sees that VPN and the VPN handles the true destinations. I understand that it is impossible to hide the VPN connection itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not hide the request.

1- When you want to access a domain name example.com a DNS query is sent. This will resolve the Name to IP address, once you have the IP address you try to connect to that server. 
2- You can be log on the DNS server by doing the request, second the proxy company or server will know that you want to establish a connection with X IP address, they can do a reverse lookup and get the domains associated with the IP.

If you manage to hide/change the domain they can get the information because of the IP address.

If you don't want them to see your request then you must use a VPN server and connect to another network, but again you are going to do the logs on the other DNS etc for your current IP(VPN assigned IP).

Comment: can you elaborate that last part about the VPN? The proxy IP needs to be the IP visisble to the end server though.

Comment: Why you want to hide the Domain/Ip address? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: My proxy is blocking certain domains which I still want to use.

Comment: your proxy my be resolving those domains to nowhere or just bloking the ip address, you can't go out by using a proxy because you can not hide the IP address (you need to connect somewhere), you may need to use a VPN server for this purpose.

Comment: so i can setup `my server` -> `proxy` -> `vpn` -> `example.com` ?

Comment: you have to connect to a VPN then you are on another network, so you bypass your current provider firewall. You are not going to resolve it with a curl with php.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the `--resolve` flag for curl  (`curl http://www.example.com --resolve www.example.com:80:127.0.0.1`) I believe that this sends an extra header in the request. the proxy shoud get only the IP address. You cannot mask that from the proxy by this message. This will work as long as the domain is hosted on a server with multiple domains, otherwise the domain gan be inferred from the IP.

The only other way I see, is to use some sort of onion routing request.